# How to debug a scratch file in Pycharm

Tags: debugging, python-3.x, pycharm, scratch-file

I am running python3.5 from a venv and am using PyCharm 5.  My debugger works fine on normal scripts but doesn't allow me to step through my code at all on a scratch file.  Is this normal?  It won't even let me set breakpoints.  Its driving me bonkers that I can't debug them!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in pycharm 5.0 - [PY-17575 Can no longer set breakpoints in scratch files](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17575)